Can neither load checkpoints, generate images, or change settings
Each time I load up Automatic 1111 via webui-user.bat everything shows a timer and nothing loads. This start this morning and I've made no changes. Any guidance is appreciated

webui-user.bat has the following
@echo off

set PYTHON=
set GIT=
set VENV_DIR=
set COMMANDLINE_ARGS= --api --xformers 

git pull

call webui.bat

